# Removing Activity from backstack not working using FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to clear the calling activity from the back stack(So that user is not able to go back on that activity) after the user navigates to another activity. I saw other questions and found that I may need to use FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK which only seemed logical, but somehow its not working.

What am I not getting ? What changes do I have to make??
Regards.

Here's the code

```
 public void silentLogin(String username,String password)
{
    user = dbHelper.getUser(username,password);
    if(user!=null) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("USER_OBJECT",user);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        Log.d("Info","Performing silent login now...");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this,"not registered",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove the calling activity from the backstack, just call finish() after starting the new activity.  Finished activities are not on the backstack.